# Series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^{3^n-1}\left(3\cdot3^n+kx\right)^{-z }$ with $\Re(z)>1$ and $ x > -3$ real

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Assume that $\Re(z)>1$ and $x\in \mathbb R$ with $ x > -3$.

Is it possible to compute $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{3^n-1} \frac1 { \left(3\times3^n+kx\right)^z }\ ?$$

I believe that this sum is related in some way to the Riemann zeta function, but I can not prove it.

Comment: A context would be helpful, since it may be a special case of a known function.

Comment: @EFinat : I believe that this sum is related in some way to the Riemann zeta function, but I can not prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a **formal computation** to relate your function with Hurwitz zeta-function
$$
\zeta(s,x)=\sum_{k\ge0}\frac1{(x+k)^s}.
$$

I **assume** convergence and a correct domain of definition:

\begin{align}
\notag\sum_{n\ge0}\sum_{k=0}^{3^n-1}\frac1{\left(3^{n+1}+kx\right)^z}&=
\sum_{n\ge0}\sum_{k\ge0}\frac1{\left(3^{n+1}+kx\right)^z}
-\sum_{n\ge0}\sum_{k\ge3^n}\frac1{\left(3^{n+1}+kx\right)^z}\\
\notag &=\sum_{n\ge0}\sum_{k\ge0}\frac1{\left(3^{n+1}+kx\right)^z}
-\sum_{n\ge0}\sum_{k\ge0}\frac1{\left(3^{n+1}+(k+3^n)x\right)^z}\\
\notag &=\sum_{n\ge0}\sum_{k\ge0}\frac1{\left(3^{n+1}+kx\right)^z}
-\sum_{n\ge0}\sum_{k\ge0}\frac1{\left(3^{n}(x+3)+kx\right)^z}\\
\notag &=x^{-z}\sum_{n\ge0}\sum_{k\ge0}\frac1{\left(3^{n+1}/x+k\right)^z}
-x^{-z}\sum_{n\ge0}\sum_{k\ge0}\frac1{\left(3^{n}(x+3)/x+k\right)^z}\\
\notag &=x^{-z}\sum_{n\ge0}\zeta\left(z,3^{n+1}/x\right)
-x^{-z}\sum_{n\ge0}\zeta\left(z,3^{n}(x+3)/x\right).
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is much hope for an exact expression; for small $x$ a series expansion gives closed-form results, the first three terms are

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{3^n-1} \frac1 { \left(3^{n+1}+kx\right)^z }=\frac{3^{2z-1} \left(4-3^{z}-3^{1-z}\right)}{\left(3^{z-1}-1\right) \left(3^z-1\right) \left(3^{z+1}-1\right)}$$
$$\qquad\qquad+\,x\frac{3^{2 z-1} z}{\left(3^z-1\right) \left(3^{z+1}-1\right)}-x^2\frac{ 3^{2 z-4} \left(3^z+5\right) (z-1) z}{2 \left(3^{z-1}-1\right) \left(3^z-1\right) \left(3^{z+1}-1\right)}+{\cal O}(x^3)$$